# How to split an image using edge detection in python

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, opencv, edge-detection

My images are stored in an `numpy` array I want to split the images into individual images containing single character.

[image]

```py
import cv2

# Load image, grayscale, Gaussian blur, Otsu's threshold, dilate
image =   arr               #numpy_arr_containing 200X200 image
original = image.copy()
gray = image
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (15,15))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=2)

# Find contours, obtain bounding box coordinates, and extract ROI
cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
image_number = 0
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 3)
    ROI = original[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imwrite("ROI_{}.png".format(image_number), ROI)
    image_number += 1

# cv2.imshow('image', image)
# cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
# cv2.imshow('dilate', dilate)
# cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: What is it that you can't do ? (please don't repeat the title)

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask] (do the research), [mre] (your post lacks input data)